# What is wrong with my observable pattern?

Tags: javascript

I'm testing the observable pattern in javascript. My callbacks in the array never seem to execute. What is wrong with my syntax?

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    var Book = function (value) {

        var onChanging = [];
        this.name = function () {

            for (var i = 0; i < onChanging.length; i++) {
                onChanging[i]();
            }

            return value;
        }

        this.addTest = function (fn) {
            onChanging.push(fn);
        }

    }

    var b = new Book(13);
    b.addTest(function () { console.log("executing");  return true; }); 
    b.name = 15;
</script>
```

Comment: why you tried `b.name = 15;` instead of `b.name();` since name is function?

Comment: "my array never seems to execute" An array is data. By definition, it cannot execute. Can you be more explicit about what you expect this code to do? Also describe what it actually does.

Comment: Perhaps you want `this.onChanging` instead of `var onChanging` as well...

Comment: You are overwriting your name function when you do `b.name = 15`

Answer (score 0):

From your code above it looks like you need to call your function name instead of assigning a value something like:

```
var b = new Book(13);
b.addTest(function () { console.log("executing");  return true; }); 
b.name(); //<-- Before b.name = 15
```

Comment: Except that you cannot change the value of name now.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `b.name = 15` doesn't execute the function, it just overwrites the value of b.name.

You could use getters and setters to react to a changing value. [See John Resig's blog post](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) or the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get)

I edited your code to use them:

```
var Book = function (value) {

     this.onChanging = [];
     this._name = "";    
 }

 Book.prototype = {
     addTest: function (fn) {
         this.onChanging.push(fn);
     },
     get name() {
         return this._name;
     },
     set name(val) {
         for (var i = 0; i < this.onChanging.length; i++) {
             this.onChanging[i](val);
         }
         this._name = val;
     }
 };

 var b = new Book(13);
 b.addTest(function (val) {
     console.log("executing", val);
     return true;
 });
 b.name = 15;
 b.name = 17;
```

**[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sefm3k5b/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a more generic solution that can work for all your properties without having to define the getters and setters, a lot of frameworks use this approach.

```
Book = function () {
     this._events = [];
     this._rawdata = {};    
}

Book.prototype = {
     bind: function (fn) {
     this._events.push(fn);
},

// pass the property, and it returns its value, pass the value and it sets it!

attr: function (property, val) {
     if (typeof val === "undefined") return this._rawdata[property];
     this._rawdata[property] = val; 
     for (var i = 0; i < this._events.length; i++)

         // we pass out the val and the property
         this._events[i](val, property);
     }
 };

b = new Book();

b.bind(function (val) {
     console.log("executing", val);
     return true;
});

b.attr("name","The Hobbit");
b.attr("SKU" ,1700109393901);

console.log(b.attr("name")); // --> The Hobbit
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wv4ch6as/

Of course you would want to change the binder so that you can bind onto properties not one bind for all properties, but I think this gets the idea.